# PIL Photoimages don't display on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, garbage-collection, python-imaging-library

I know this a common problem, but I can't seem to solve it myself. My images don't display on Tkinter. I did research, and it seems that the problem is garbage collection. I tried everything to stop it, but it seems that nothing works. Here's my full code :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from lxml import etree
from os import walk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class Gui(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.frames = {}
        self.l_widgets = {}
        self.images = []  # Unused, doesn't work (nor does a dictionary)
        # self.arbre = etree.parse("characters.xml") #relative path
        self.arbre = etree.parse("C:/Users/nolan/OneDrive/Bureau/Code/wovnot/characters.xml")  # absolute path
        self.roles = {}
        for root in self.arbre.xpath('//wolvesville'):
            for pool in root.xpath('pool'):
                self.roles[str(pool.get("name"))] = {}
                for role in pool.xpath("character"):
                    self.roles[str(pool.get("name"))][role.get("name")] = (
                        role.get("surname"),
                        role.get("surname2"),
                        "r" + role.get("random"))
        self.command = {}

    def add_frame(self, name, grid_args=None, frame="main"):
        if grid_args is None:
            grid_args = {}
        if frame == "main":
            self.frames[name] = ttk.Frame(self)
        else:
            self.frames[name] = ttk.Frame(self.frames[frame])
        self.frames[name].grid(**grid_args)

    def create_entry(self, name, config_args=None, grid_args=None, frame="main"):
        if grid_args is None:
            grid_args = {}
        if config_args is None:
            config_args = {}
        if frame == "main":
            self.l_widgets[name] = (ttk.Entry(self), tk.StringVar())
        else:
            self.l_widgets[name] = (ttk.Entry(self.frames[frame]), tk.StringVar())
        self.l_widgets[name][0].config(textvariable=self.l_widgets[name][1], **config_args)
        self.l_widgets[name][0].grid(**grid_args)

    def create_notebook(self, name, config_args=None, grid_args=None, frame="main"):
        if grid_args is None:
            grid_args = {}
        if config_args is None:
            config_args = {}
        if frame == "main":
            self.l_widgets[name] = (ttk.Notebook(self, **config_args), 0)
        else:
            self.l_widgets[name] = (ttk.Notebook(self.frames[frame], **config_args), 0)
        self.l_widgets[name][0].grid(**grid_args)

    def add_image(self, name, filename, size=(None, None)):
        """Unused, doesn't work"""
        image_temp = Image.open(filename)
        if size != (None, None):
            image_temp.thumbnail(size)
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_temp)
        self.images[name] = image
        return image

    def create_a_label_with_an_image(self, name, filename, size=(None, None), config_args=None, grid_args=None,
                                     frame="main"):
        global immortals
        if grid_args is None:
            grid_args = {}
        if config_args is None:
            config_args = {}
        immortals[name] = ImagePersistent(filename, size).image
        self.l_widgets[name] = (ttk.Label(self.frames[frame]), immortals[name])
        self.l_widgets[name][0].config(**config_args)
        self.l_widgets[name][0].image = immortals[name]
        self.l_widgets[name][0].grid(**grid_args)

    def add_to_notebook(self, name, name_frame, config_args=None, grid_args=None):
        if grid_args is None:
            grid_args = {}
        if config_args is None:
            config_args = {}
        self.frames[name_frame] = ttk.Frame(self)
        self.l_widgets[name][0].add(self.frames[name_frame], **config_args)
        self.l_widgets[name][0].grid(**grid_args)


class ImagePersistent:
    def __init__(self, path, size=(None, None)):
        self.path = path
        self.temp = Image.open(path)
        if size != (None, None):
            self.temp.thumbnail(size)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.temp)


# END################################################################################################################################################################"""


global immortals
immortals = {}
# also tried globals().update({"immortals":{}})
# and immortals.update({name: thing})
g = Gui()

# mypath = "icons/characters"
mypath = "C:/Users/nolan/OneDrive/Bureau/Code/wovnot/icons/characters"
filenames = next(walk(mypath), (None, None, []))[2]  # [] if no file
if not filenames:
    raise Warning("no icons found")

print(filenames)

g.create_notebook("roles", grid_args={"rowspan": 4, "column": 0})
for pool in g.roles.keys():
    g.add_to_notebook("roles", str(pool), config_args={"text": str(pool)})
    nbr_images = 0
    for icon in filenames:
        if icon[:-4] in g.roles[pool].keys():
            g.create_a_label_with_an_image(icon[:-4], mypath + "/" + icon,
                                           size=(50, 50),
                                           grid_args={"row": nbr_images // 12,
                                                      "column": nbr_images % 12},
                                           frame=str(pool))
            nbr_images += 1

g.mainloop()
```

Here's solutions for garbage collecting that seems to work with others didn't solve the problem :

1. Referencing each image as a variable.
   Not possible in my case (I won't know how many I have at start) and while trying to do this for one image, it still wasn't shown.
2. Keeping a reference with label.image = image.
   It's in my code, doesn't work. `self.l_widgets[name][0].image = immortals[name]`,line
3. Using  a class.
   The ImagePersistent class didn't work either.
4. Using a list/dictionnary/tuple.
   self.images doesn't work, not does putting it in self.l_widgets
5. Using a global variable.
   Immortals doesn't work. I also tried globals().update({"immortals":{}}) and immortals.update({name: thing}).

So i don't know. It's still gridded, and when I didn't use a class it worked! I feel like I've tried everything. I can give links to the images (all RGBA pngs) if needed. I know they do exist, since nbr_images values goes to 57.

Comment: Lots of code to look into...

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that the code that creates the image is being called for every image? Have you verified that your calculation of the row and column are correct?  Using a list or dictionary will definitely work when done correctly. If that isn't happening, then maybe you have a logic problem. Please try to reduce this code down to a [mcve].

Comment: You haven't assigned the image to `image` option of `ttk.Label(...)`.  `self.l_widgets[name][0].image = immortals[name]` does not set the image option of the label, just keep a reference of the image using *an attribute* of the label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to put image as an attribute in the config part. This code works :

```
def create_a_label_with_an_image(self, name, filename,size=(None,None), config_args=None, grid_args=None, frame="main"):
        global immortals
        if grid_args is None:
            grid_args = {}
        if config_args is None:
            config_args = {}
        immortals[name] = ImagePersistent(filename, size).image
        self.l_widgets[name] = (ttk.Label(self.frames[frame]), immortals[name])
        self.l_widgets[name][0].config(**config_args, image=immortals[name])
        self.l_widgets[name][0].image = immortals[name]
        self.l_widgets[name][0].grid(**grid_args)
```

Thanks @acw1668 for telling me. I'll close the subject.